# how to get buffer for file specified on command line?

Tags: init-file, buffers

Let's assume I invoke EMACS (24.3.1) always with just one file name to visit.  How do I get the buffer for that file while in my .EMACS startup?  I tried it and the function (current-buffer) will return my *scratch* buffer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the variable `command-line-args` to get a list of elements making up the command line used to invoke emacs. If your command line consists of just two elements — `"emacs"` and the filename to visit — you can get the buffer associated with the file visited like this:

```
(get-buffer (file-name-nondirectory (cadr command-line-args)))
```

However, this won't work in your `.emacs` startup file because the buffer for the file being visited isn't available yet. Instead, you can add code to your `.emacs` file to add something like the above to the `emacs-startup-hook`, which is run after command line arguments are handled. For example, this code augments the hook to set a variable named `cmd-line-file-buffer` to the buffer of the file being visited:

```
(add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook
      (lambda ()
        (if (= 2 (length command-line-args))
            (setq cmd-line-file-buffer
                  (get-buffer (file-name-nondirectory (cadr command-line-args)))))))
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues to solve: the `.emacs` file is loaded too early, and there are multiple buffers in a running instance of Emacs, even just after startup.

The first issue is solved by putting your code in `emacs-startup-hook`, as pointed out in the other answers.  The second issue is solved by ignoring any buffers that don't have any associated files:

```
(defun my-file-buffers ()
  (remove nil
          (mapcar #'(lambda (buffer) (and (buffer-file-name buffer) buffer))
                  (buffer-list))))

(add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook
          #'(lambda ()
              (message "The following buffers are interesting today: %s"
                       (my-file-buffers))))
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is because the init file is loaded and run before the file to visit is loaded.  You could use the [hook](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Hooks.html#Hooks) `after-load-functions` to run code just after the file to visit is loaded.  For example, put this in your init file:

```el
(add-hook 'after-load-functions (lambda (f) (setq my-buffer (current-buffer))))
```